Opensearch/Elasticsearch Must_Not Clause not Accepting a List
I'm trying to write an Opensearch query which will exclude any results which match a list of terms. Per what I can tell in Opensearch documentation, this sort of behavior should be supported.
However, of the two queries I have below, only the one which doesn't use a list (working_query) works. Unfortunately, googling / searching stackoverflow for the error hasn't yielded any results that seem relevant. Thanks in advance!
working_query =  {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "textContent": {
                        "query": "must_phrase",
                        "slop": 10,
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {"match_phrase": {"textContent": "should_phrase"}},
                    ]
                }
            },
        ],
        "must_not":[
            {"match_phrase":{"folderIdentifier.identifierValue":'elem1'}}
        ],
    }
}


broken_query =  {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "textContent": {
                        "query": "must_phrase",
                        "slop": 10,
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {"match_phrase": {"textContent": "should_phrase"}},
                    ]
                }
            },
        ],
        "must_not":[
            {"match_phrase":{"folderIdentifier.identifierValue":['elem1','elem2']}}
        ],
    }
}


Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RequestError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[56], line 25
      1 broken_query =  {
      2     "bool": {
      3         "must": [
   (...)
     23     }
     24 }
---> 25 test=search_docs_full(broken_query)

Cell In[11], line 29, in search_docs_full(text_query)
     25 if last_hit != 0:
     26     query['search_after'] = [last_hit]
---> 29 results = searchwrapper.client.search(index=index_name,body=query, request_timeout=1200)
     30 if len(results['hits']['hits']) != 0:
     31     previous_hit = last_hit

File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opensearchpy/client/utils.py:181, in query_params.<locals>._wrapper.<locals>._wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    178         if v is not None:
    179             params[p] = _escape(v)
--> 181 return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opensearchpy/client/__init__.py:1742, in OpenSearch.search(self, body, index, params, headers)
   1739 if "from_" in params:
   1740     params["from"] = params.pop("from_")
-> 1742 return self.transport.perform_request(
   1743     "POST",
   1744     _make_path(index, "_search"),
   1745     params=params,
   1746     headers=headers,
   1747     body=body,
   1748 )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opensearchpy/transport.py:448, in Transport.perform_request(self, method, url, params, body, timeout, ignore, headers)
    446             raise e
    447     else:
--> 448         raise e
    450 else:
    451     # connection didn't fail, confirm its live status
    452     self.connection_pool.mark_live(connection)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opensearchpy/transport.py:409, in Transport.perform_request(self, method, url, params, body, timeout, ignore, headers)
    406 connection = self.get_connection()
    408 try:
--> 409     status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(
    410         method,
    411         url,
    412         params,
    413         body,
    414         headers=headers,
    415         ignore=ignore,
    416         timeout=timeout,
    417     )
    419     # Lowercase all the header names for consistency in accessing them.
    420     headers_response = {
    421         header.lower(): value for header, value in headers_response.items()
    422     }

File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opensearchpy/connection/http_requests.py:232, in RequestsHttpConnection.perform_request(self, method, url, params, body, timeout, allow_redirects, ignore, headers)
    219 if (
    220     not (200 <= response.status_code < 300)
    221     and response.status_code not in ignore
    222 ):
    223     self.log_request_fail(
    224         method,
    225         url,
   (...)
    230         raw_data,
    231     )
--> 232     self._raise_error(
    233         response.status_code,
    234         raw_data,
    235         response.headers.get("Content-Type"),
    236     )
    238 self.log_request_success(
    239     method,
    240     url,
   (...)
    245     duration,
    246 )
    248 return response.status_code, response.headers, raw_data

File ~/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opensearchpy/connection/base.py:316, in Connection._raise_error(self, status_code, raw_data, content_type)
    313 except (ValueError, TypeError) as err:
    314     logger.warning("Undecodable raw error response from server: %s", err)
--> 316 raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(
    317     status_code, error_message, additional_info
    318 )

RequestError: RequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', '[1:325] [bool] failed to parse field [must_not]')


match_phrase dosen't support array as values you need to change this
{"match_phrase":{"folderIdentifier.identifierValue":['elem1','elem2']}}

to this
"bool":{

    "should":[
    {"match_phrase":{"folderIdentifier.identifierValue":'elem1'}},
    {"match_phrase":{"folderIdentifier.identifierValue":'elem2'}}]}


Ah, thank you! What will support an array?

terms query support array but it doesn't analyze your text for example if you re looking for the two word 'Elastic' 'Search' using the standard analyzer on a field of type text you need to search with {"terms":{"field_name":["elastic","search"]}} instead if you use {"terms":{"field_name":["Elastic","Search"]}}the result will be empty
